# Combine www and no-www sites status in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, no-www

I added a URL to my Webmaster Tools account which was the `www` URL version of my website. Recently I understood that pages doesn't index in "Index status", so I added another website which was the `no-www` URL of my site. Now I can see that the pages are indexed.

But how can I combine both of them together to see the result of both of them as one website?

Comment: I advise you to either redirect 302 one of them or at least use the canonical meta tag in header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your Google Webmaster Tools account, for both `www` version and `no-www` version, in the *site setting* select your *Preferred domain*.

For example, if you preferred your website known as `example.com` instead of `www.example.com`, then choose the *Display URLs as `example.com`*. Remember you need to set this for both version.

Then, make sure every time user access to `www.example.com` will be redirect to `example.com`.

Comment: Is google OK with this? in the other words, it wont make any problem?

Comment: please refer to https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en

Comment: it still have two different sites and different sets of stats? Should Index status stats not be the same now? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *.htaccess* redirect if Apache is serving your website or another server side redirect.

Make two websites in Google Webmaster Tools.
Set the preferred domain in Google Webmaster Tools.
Nowadays, Google Webmaster Tools added a "Create a set" option.
So create a new set, name it and add as members those two properties (websites) to it.

If you have SSL installed and HTTPS activated you should add two websites more.

> `https://www.example.com/` - Records data only for the HTTPS version of your site. You must add HTTP and HTTPS versions of your site as separate properties.

[What URL should I use? - Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en)